# Tabbed VS Tree for navigaion. Which is the preferred approach?

Tags: toad

I realize that in of TOAD books right, it justifies the reaons on why it uses tabbed pane is that tree view involves too much scrolling.

But for me i like tree view better. As it only shows you the top level.
I see TOAD user interface. i thought the tabbed panels was very confusing for me to switch around.

What are your opinions regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I think in general if you are designing the interface, I think it depends on the number of items you are trying to display.

in your TOAD example. (which i am assuming is Toad from www.quest.com) the tabs only serve to remove 1 level (the top level) from your tree.

The advantage the tree structure has is that you can 'drill down' from  scheme to table to trigger, etc..

so it really depends on what you are trying to achieve, or the style you want to work with.